# Query return null and cannot find error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following relations

```
Supplies            
sid     1       2       3       4
sname   Jason   David   John    Peter
address 1a      2b      3c      4d


Parts                       
pid     10      20      30      40
pname   Head    Body    Hand    Leg
color   red     blue    green   white


Catalog             
sid 1   1   2   2   3   4   1
pid 10  20  20  30  30  40  30
cost100 200 150 150 130 125 50
```

and I want to find that the the supplies' ID who supply some red and some green parts.

1. I use the query but return null and I don't know why? (It should return sid is 1)

   ```
   SELECT S.sid
   FROM Suppliers AS S, Parts AS P, Catalog AS C
   WHERE S.sid = C.sid
   AND C.pid = P.pid
   AND (
   P.color =  'red'
   AND P.color =  'green'
   )
   ```
2. And I want to ask that what is the difference between the above and the following query?
   (It also return null but I think it should return sid is 1)

   ```
   SELECT S.sid
   FROM Suppliers AS S, Parts AS P1, Catalog AS C1, Parts AS P2 , Catalog AS C2
   WHERE S.sid = C1.sid
   AND C1.pid = P1.pid
   AND S.sid = C2.pid
   AND C2.pid = P2.pid
   AND (
   P1.color =  'red'
   AND P2.color =  'green'
   )
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first query your trying to find any Part that is both red and green. No such row can exist.

In your second query you are joining in the Parts table and Catalog table twice so so you are now trying to find a Part that is red in a Catalog that also have another Catalog with a Part that is green. This is probably what you want.

However, you have a small misstake in your WHERE statement

```
WHERE S.sid = C1.sid
AND S.sid = C2.pid  <-- error is here, it should be C2.sid
```

There is a cleaner way of writing this query. It's not faster but easier to read. Note that I've renamed the table Catalog into cata since sqlfiddle doesn't like the word catalog.

```
select s.sid 
  from suppliers s
  join cata cr on s.sid = cr.sid
  join parts pr on pr.pid = cr.pid and pr.color = 'red'
  join cata cg on s.sid = cg.sid
  join parts pg on pg.pid = cg.pid and pg.color = 'green';
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac1cc/5)

Answer (score 3):

In your first query :

`P.color` cannot be equal to `red` `**AND**` `green` at the same time

The second query is just wrong because there are same tables joined twice with different alias.

Comment: The second query doesn't work. The correct returned data in this case is NULL because you cannot match twice colors at the same time. It is returning a row because the query find a row with color red and another with color green.

Comment: The second query is actually find except for the error in the WHERE. Joining in Catalog and Parts twice is the right thing to do.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand you are right, I have already +1 your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not finding any matches so it is returning an empty answer set or "null"

Try removing the selection criteria one "And" at a time until you get something in the answer set and then work on determining why that single selection criteria (the one you removed just before it started working)is not making a match and change it accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1.Totally agree with **sdespont**. So Modify your first `Query` to something like this

```
SELECT S.sid
FROM Suppliers AS S
inner join Catalog AS C on C.SID=S.SID
inner join Parts AS P on P.PID=C.PID
WHERE
P.color =  'red'
AND
P.color =  'green'
```

2.The second `Query` also has the **same** issues as with **first one**. Also you don't need to join **same** table `twice`.

Comment: This query will find parts that are _either_ red or green, that is not what OP wants.

Comment: Now you've done the same error as OP did. No Part can be both red and green

Answer (score 1):

You want to find suppliers from whom you can purchase red parts as well as green parts. These suppliers stock both colors.

When you `cannot find error` it can be helpful to write the query so that the subsets are clearly demarcated, like Venn diagrams. This can be done with inline views. The syntax may seem less concise but concise syntax does not correlate with performance; inline views can perform very well especially if you work with id-lists and don't pull in any extraneous data.

In the following, we interesect the id-list of suppliers offering red parts with the id-list of suppliers offering green parts, and then intersect that back again with the suppliers table when we want to grab all of the supplier data we may need (name, phone#, address, fax number, sales rep name, etc etc).

```
      select * from suppliers

           join

           (



            select redsuppliers.sid   
             from

           (
            select sid 
            from catalog join parts
            on catalog.pid = parts.pid
            where parts.color = 'red'
            ) redsuppliers

            join


           (
            select sid 
            from catalog join parts
            on catalog.pid = parts.pid
            where parts.color = 'green'
            ) greensuppliers
           on redsuppliers.sid=greensuppliers.sid



           ) as SuppliersWithBothColors

          on suppliers.sid = SuppliersWithBothColors.sid
```